# Shared file storage for a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, network-storage

I have a rails app that accepts file uploads and I wanted to know the best way to have common storage between servers.  Since we have a number of windows applications we have used samba in the past, but as we build pure linux apps I would like to do this the best possible way.

We are expecting large amounts of data, so would need to scale this across multiple file servers.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) with an S3 backend.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have all the data in-house than a networked file-system might be the way to go. Try setting up [AFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System) it scales pretty good.

Comment: AFS isn't better than any other filesystem when you need read-write everywhere.  You can't have read/write replicates, and releasing a volume after every write would be quite expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Another good alternative is from the creators of Memcached:

Mogile FS
http://www.danga.com/mogilefs/

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it is to use attachment_fu with an S3 backend.